# Преобразование голосов в звездочки при переносе расширенной дискуссии в чат

Tags: предложение

Насколько реалистично при конвертации комментариев в чат запилить добавление звёздочек к сообщениям, за полезность которых кто-то ранее проголосовал?

Answer (score 7):

Такой вопрос поднимался на Общей Мете: [Transfer upvotes on comments to stars in chat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/259469/383809) (+ [дубликат 1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/295472/383809), [дубликат 2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/289230/383809)). А также — [на английском Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/297096/2452869). По моей оценке содержание этого запроса практически полностью соответствует вопросу здесь.

Вкратце, существует несколько проблем, которые были указаны:

- Голоса за комментарии и звездочки имеют разное значение. Голоса за комментарии, в основном, означают **полезность**, тогда как звездочки часто используются для обозначение, **чего-то важного или просто смешного**. Разница, разумеется, субъективна, не всегда очевидна, но все же существует. ([раз](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/259474/383809), [два](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/299852/383809), подсказка  на голосование за комментарий "*Комментарий добавляет **полезную** информацию к сообщение*", подсказка к звездочке в чате "*star this message as **useful/interesting***")
- Не у всех проголосовавших пользователей за комментарий есть аккаунт (или даже привилегия) в чате. Даже если пользователи без привилегий смогут быть в чате конкретно в комнате с перенесенными вопросами, это все же снижает "переносимость" голосов в звездочки.
- [Аргумент Shog9](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297196/2452869), что мы ничего полезного не делаем с этими "зазвежжеными" сообщениями, следовательно зачем.

Лично я не нахожу эти аргументы до конца убедительными, и считаю что такой функционал вполне можно и было бы очень неплохо реализовать.

Я начал [конкурс на вопрос на общей мете, уже указанный в самом начале](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/259469/383809). Если вы заинтересованы в реализации такого функционала, пожалуйста, проголосуйте там и\или оставьте свои аргументы в виде ответа. [Вот моя аргументация](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/355522/383809).